# Is Managed Identities using ADAL?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

Is Managed Identities using Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL), especially for this command from the doc[1]?

```
curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F' -H Metadata:true
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you interested in the implementation details? Your app does not use ADAL to call that endpoint. What it uses internally to do certificate-based authentication, only MS developers can know that.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The reason why I asked is because ADAL is migrating into MSAL. If managed identity is using ADAL, we will need to do the migration by June 30, 2022.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration.

Comment: Ok, well we don't have access to the code that Managed Identity uses internally, so we cannot say what it is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use managed identities, without worrying about having to migrate to something else due to the guidance for ADAL deprecation. There is no use of ADAL in this flow, and any internal dependencies in this regard are handled by Microsoft.